# TypeError in reverse resolution of URLs in production environment

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a production only error regarding the Reverse resolution of URL. My template code is the following:

```
{% for result in result_list %}
<div class="result">

{% if grh_out %}
<form action= "{% url 'result_show' forloop.counter0 %}" method="post">
{% endif %}

...
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works without errors on the Django development server. However, when migrated to a production server, the line `"{% url 'result_show' forloop.counter0 %}"` generates a TypeError. I have turned on the debug on the production server to try to trace the error, and found that it occurs in `...django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix`:

```
candidate = (prefix_norm + result) % dict(zip(prefix_args + params, unicode_args))
```

The local variables are the following:

```
val             0
pattern         'result_show/(\\d+)'
self            <RegexURLResolver 'expofit_web.urls' (None:None) ^/>
args            (0,)
_prefix         u'/~amartino/'
possibility     [(u'result_show/%(_0)s', [u'_0'])]
unicode_args    [u'0']
possibilities   [([(u'result_show/%(_0)s', [u'_0'])], 'result_show/(\\d+)', {})]
lookup_view     u'result_show'
prefix_norm     u'/%7Eamartino/'
prefix_args     []
params          [u'_0']
result          u'result_show/%(_0)s'
defaults            {}
kwargs          {}
```

What is different in the production environment that could affect this?

Comment: the value of this `forloop.counter0` is 0 which is not allow. Why you put that counter?

Comment: @catherine Asked the question on the IRC channel. It seems that it's a bug. They said the problem is i `u'/%7Eamartino/'`. The ~ is being interpreted as %7. I'm still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [bug in Django 1.5](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20022). The patch is applyed to the main branch on  [github](https://github.com/django/django).